# Alternative for WL.SimpleDialog

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to migrate a mobilefirst-based application from version 7.x to 8.0. I am working a web application with the mobilefirst 8.0 Web SDK.

Is there an alternative in MFP 8 for the `WL.SimpleDialog` API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually talked about Cordova apps (based on your comment to this answer), then Cordova apps that cordova-plugin-mfp is installed to also have cordova-plugin-dialogs installed as well automatically. This plug-in enables native dialogs for each supported Cordova platform. You can review its usage guidelines, here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs

The above is meant as a replacement for the removed `WL.SimpleDialog` API.

If you are in fact refer to "web apps" (not Cordova) then you can instead use any custom plug-in to create dialogs. A simple google search for "dialog javascript plugin" will produce endless results: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=dialog+javascript+framework%22&oq=dialog+javascript+framework%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3408j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=dialog+javascript+plugin%22

Comment: WL.SimpleDialog was useful also in native popups (depending on mobile OS), whatever thank you

Comment: See my edited answer. cordova-plugin-dialogs is automatically installed in Cordova apps. By using its API it will produce native dialogs in each used Cordova platform. Google for its API.